# Docker volumes not binding

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have been pulling my hair out over this issue which seems very simple but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to set up an nginx container that serves some dynamic html reports on different ports. To accomplish this I am trying to bind volumes containing the html files to the correct location.

The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  report-host:
    build: ./host
    image: host:latest
    network_mode: 'host'
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - ./5000/:/var/www/port5000/
      - ./5001/:/var/www/port5001/
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

The 5000 and 5001 directories are located in the same directory as the docker-compose file and both contain an index.html file.

The dockerfile that builds the host image is pretty straightforward:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Create the volume directories
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/port5000/ && mkdir -p /var/www/port5001/
```

Finally, the conf file is barebones since it really doesn't need anything special

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen       5000;
        root         /var/www/port5000/;
    }

    server {
        listen       5001;
        root         /var/www/port5001/;
    }
}
```

However, when I run `docker-compose run report-host ls var/www/port5000` the directory exists but is just empty. When opening localhost:5000 it just gives me a page not found message.

Why aren't the volumes binding in this case? I have several other projects that do the exact same and they do bind correctly...

Update: I was messing around some and at some point the port5000 folder now got a subfolder that is in my volume, but it is still empty. The other folder has the same structure but that volume does not contain the subfolder. I am starting to think that something completely insane is happening and I will try to completely uninstall docker and then reinstall to try and fix the issue.

Comment: On what platform are you running docker?

Comment: `docker exec` into container. then check

Comment: @larsks I am running docker on Windows 10 with Docker for Windows

Comment: I don't have docker on windows to test this out, but here's the thing: your docker isn't actually running on Windows. It's running on a Linux virtual machine that is running on Windows, and that VM has it's own filesystem. It is likely that your local Windows filesystem isn't getting exposed correctly. I don't know how or if that's supposed to work, but maybe that will suggest some avenues of investigation.  Or maybe someone will drop by who is more familiar with Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my password a few days ago and apparently that was the issue. I updated the credentials in the Docker for Windows Shared Drives menu which let files be exposed correctly.

Thanks to @larsks for setting me on the path to figuring out the problem.